# Eclipse, bundle projects and run them separately

Tags: java, eclipse

Is there a way in eclipse so i can bundle my standalone java applications and bundle them like into one solution?

And then when I press the debug/run button that it starts all those projects? (and also builds them)

Answer (score 0):

Its not directly an eclipse tool, but you could have a look at [maven](http://maven.apache.org/), [ant](http://ant.apache.org/) or a different build system. Those integrate with eclipse.